# How to compare performance Web Service implemented in two or more framework?

Tags: java, performance, web-services, rest, soap

At the University I have project to do: Performance comparison of two or more Web services implemented in different framework. So is a good idea to compare Axis2, CXF and Metro (All three will use SOAP) or is it better to compare sevice that uses the SOAP with service that uses REST (eg Axis2 and Jersey)?

How can I measure the performance all services on two computers in the home network? Should I measure response time by the client class?

Comment: Define performance : response time, memory consumption... there's several metrics that could define "performance"... And it makes more sense to compare WS with the same protocol if you want to measure performance of the framework : payload should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To measure performance I would create a web service client that log exact time measurements for each call, that you can analyze later. Take a look at System.nanoTime to get exact timings.

I would choose both REST and SOAP to make a proper comparison. If you have a framework that does both it would be interesting to test the following combos:

- REST: Framework which only does REST
- SOAP: Framework which only does SOAP
- REST: Framework which only both REST and SOAP
- SOAP: Framework which only both REST and SOAP

Then you can evaluate both framework performance and perhaps draw some general conslusions on performance between REST and SOAP.